# valgrind Invalid read of size 8

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm trying to understand why Valgrind reports a "Invalid read of size 4" error. Code compile and give correct output on Linux console.
The goal is to build a dynamic array of struct *record*(up to 10Mil items) that grow dynamically and organize its by language through the struct *list*.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "../crc64.c"

typedef struct {
  char          cat;
  uint64_t      crc;
  int           id;
} record;

typedef struct {
  int           count;
  char          *lang;
  record        **records;
} list;

record *records = NULL;
int record_count = 0;
list *lists = NULL;
int list_count = 0;

void addItemToList(record *r, char *lang){  
  int found = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i<list_count; i++){
    if(strcmp(lists[i].lang, lang) == 0){
      list *l = &lists[i];
      found = 1;      
      record **tmp  = realloc(l->records, (l->count + 1) * sizeof(record *));
      if (tmp == NULL)
        printf("Problem on realloc - records/list\n");
      else{
        l->records = tmp;
        l->count ++;
        l->records[l->count -1] = r;
      }        
      break;
    }
  }
  if(found == 0){
    list_count ++;
    list *tmp = realloc(lists, list_count  * sizeof(list));
    if(!tmp) 
      printf("Error on realloc - list");
    lists = tmp;
    lists[list_count - 1].count =1 ;
    lists[list_count - 1].lang = lang ;
    record **tmp1 = realloc(NULL, sizeof(record *));
    if(!tmp1)
      printf("Error on realloc records/list \n");          
    lists[list_count - 1].records = tmp1;      
    tmp1[0] = r;    
  }  
}

int addRecord(char cat, char *name, int id, char lang[3]){  
  record *tmp;
  if(record_count == 0){
    tmp = malloc(1 * sizeof(record));         
  }  
  else 
    tmp = realloc(records, (record_count + 1)  * sizeof(record));
  if(tmp == NULL){
    printf("Error on m(re)alloc records\n");
    return(1);
  }  

  records = tmp;
  record r = {cat, crc64(name), id};
  records[record_count ] = r; 
  addItemToList(&(records[record_count]), lang);
  record_count ++;
  return 0;  
}

int main(void){
  addRecord('l', "torino",1, "it");
  addRecord('l', "berlin",20, "de");
  addRecord('l', "paris",30, "fr");  
  addRecord('l', "hamburg",21, "de");
  addRecord('l', "sassari",2, "it");
  addRecord('l', "cagliari",3, "it");
  addRecord('l', "milano",4, "it");


  for(int i=0; i< list_count;i++){
    printf("lang: %s, count :%d\n", lists[i].lang, lists[i].count);  
    for (int z = 0; z < lists[i].count; z ++){
      printf("  crc:  %lu -   id: %d \n", lists[i].records[z]->crc, lists[i].records[z]->id);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

here output from Valgrind:

```
cc -std=c99  -O0 -g tt.c -o tt && valgrind --track-origins=yes ./tt
lang: it, count :4
==17435== Invalid read of size 4
==17435==    at 0x400BAC: main (tt.c:92)
==17435==  Address 0x51d0050 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==17435==    at 0x4C29097: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==17435==    by 0x400990: addRecord (tt.c:65)
==17435==    by 0x400A8E: main (tt.c:81)
==17435== 
==17435== Invalid read of size 8
==17435==    at 0x400BE0: main (tt.c:92)
==17435==  Address 0x51d0048 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==17435==    at 0x4C29097: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==17435==    by 0x400990: addRecord (tt.c:65)
==17435==    by 0x400A8E: main (tt.c:81)
==17435== 
  crc:  10540480176773849829 -   id: 1 
  crc:  5100567372334599520 -   id: 2 
  crc:  16805344662159858020 -   id: 3 
  crc:  16314500525507880138 -   id: 4 
lang: de, count :2
  crc:  3766391767329109829 -   id: 20 
  crc:  12127946872667643737 -   id: 21 
lang: fr, count :1
  crc:  2180538375615994033 -   id: 30
```

Answer (score 5):

You are reallocating the records, but you don't update the pointers.

```
tmp = realloc(records, (record_count + 1)  * sizeof(record));
```

When you do this, all pointers to the old  `records` array become **invalid.**

Here is a simpler example.

```
record *array = malloc(sizeof(*array));
record *r1 = &array[0];
array = realloc(array, sizeof(*array) * 2);
record *r2 = &array[1];
// r1 is probably invalid, since 'array' changed
```

There are a few ways you can fix this.

1. When you `realloc`, go through and update all the pointers.  This is a real pain.
2. Alloc every record separately, instead of in one big array.  (No, this won't waste memory.  At least not compared to the 8 bytes per record already wasted due to field order.)
3. Instead of pointers to records, use indexes into the record array.  These don't need to be updated.

Comment: Thanks, alloc every record separately is working really good. About 3th point, do you mean to store on lists only the position of records on the big array?. In this case what will happens using qsort? will in this case positions be lost?